# Language support for Help Desk application template

Tags: 2007, localization

I am trying to add a new language support to one of the application templates, specifically Help Desk application template.

Simply changing the column names crashes the application. The wsp file for the template don't include any localization strings, I think all the localization files are in the base application template.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resource file you are looking for are inside the `ApplicationTemplateCore.wsp` file, in the `Config\Resources\` and `Resources\` folders.

Here's a detailed example for the `Absence and Vacation Schedule` template:

1. **Extract the files from both WSP files** (technically they are CAB files)
2. **Translate the resources**

   - AbsenceVacationSchedule:

     1. Create a `1045` folder.
     2. Copy the contents of the `1033` folder into it.
     3. Translate all the strings in the `WEBTEMPAbsence.xml` file.
     4. Add the `1045` folder to the list in the `Manifest.xml` file.
   - ApplicationTemplateCore:

     1. Create the following files:

        - `Config\Resources\tsa.pl-pl.resx`,
        - `Resources\avm.pl-pl.resx`,
        - `Resources\tsa.pl-pl.resx`.
     2. Copy the contents of the appropriate English resource files into the newly created files.
     3. Translate all the strings.
     4. Add new files to the list in the `Manifest.xml` file.
3. **Compress all the files back into WSP templates**

   1. Download CAB SDK from one of the mirrors - [1](http://web.archive.org/web/20070403215326/http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/cab/2.0/w98nt42kmexp/en-us/cabsdk.exe) or [2](http://www.pixelsplasher.com/_downloads/software/Microsoft-Cabinet-SDK/) (the [original link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/cab/2.0/w98nt42kmexp/en-us/cabsdk.exe) seems to be dead).
   2. Extract the `CABARC.EXE` file and the `CABARC.DOC` document.
   3. Use something like `..\CABARC.EXE -p -r n ..\SiteTemplate.cab .\*` (this should be executed after changing working directory to the one containing template files) to create a CAB file and change its extension to WSP.

Comment: Thats an awesome answer Marek and very concise,if I had the reputation I would vote for it :) Thanks
Matt

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I couldn't see the localized name under the template list on the New SharePoint Site creation page when I chose the language I targeted. Any ideas?

Comment: @Élodie Petit You replaced the `1045` and `pl-pl` values with appropriate settings, right?

Comment: Welcome to our forum matt. Please keep comments like this in  comments fields to answer (i moved it)