# Cannot Create a Bilingual Site Template in Sharepoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, site-template

I'm trying to create a site template out of a bilingual sharepoint 2013 site (in SP2010 compatibility mode). I can create the template successfully, but the template only gets created in the current language that I'm in. It does not contain the translation for the other language...

Is it possible to do something of the sort? If not, what are my alternatives?

Here's the lowdown :

My site collection contains a root site and in that root site, I have multiple sub-sites which are created from the template mentioned above. Right now, the template is in English only. But I need to add a French option in it. So I go in my template site and I translate all labels by switching from language to language. Everything is fine... I switch languages and the labels are in the correct language. Now, I save the site as a template solution (with or without content, made no difference) and when I create a subsite from that template WSP, the site does not have my translated labels when I switch languages, just the hard-coded labels in English.

Help and Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The site template does not include any of the localized strings. You should open up the wsp file and manually add those.

[Language support for Help Desk application template](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4533/language-support-for-help-desk-application-template)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amal. Unfortunately in my WSP template, maybe I'm just missing something, all resources files (resources.en-US.resx) are empty and I have no 1033 folder anywhere... Not sure what to do...